# jQuery Wildcard string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an all ajax website including an ajax search. My search, when entered changes the url into this `/#!/search/Query Here/`. I already am able to detect the `/search/` but only if there is no search query and I just enter it directly. If I have a query, my code doesn't process it because it doesn't match. Is there any way for me to detect only the bold /#!**/search/** Query Here/. This is my current code:

```
var oldLoc = window.location.hash.replace(/^#\!/,"");
if (oldLoc == '/search/') {
    $('#reload_section').load('search.php');
    $('.nav_itm.home').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav_itm.account').removeClass('active');
    _currentScreen = 6;
}
```

So again I can detect it the url and load the search page but if I throw a query in there, the site just loads the home page. How do I separate everything after `/search/` into a different string and loose it on the variable `oldLoc`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, something like this (please change to incorporate into your example as needed):

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/page/#!/search/Query Here/';
var m = /(.*\/#!\/search\/)([^\/]+)/.exec(url);
if(m) {
  $('#msgs').text('match: ' + m[1] + ' ----- ' + m[2]);
} else {
  $('#msgs').text('no match');    
}
```

See this jsFiddle for a working example which you can use for testing:

- http://jsfiddle.net/zSBkL/1/

See these for more information on the above:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp
- [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

Comment: Thanks this looks like it will work. Forgot about using regex.

Comment: Actually, Im an idiot, I forgot that this is what my search looks like `/search/option1/Query Here/` and `/search/option2/Query Here/`. How can I check `if m[1] == '/search/option1/'`. I'm not good at regex at all so I couldn't even think where to begin with this. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, just use this regex instead: /(.*\/#!\/search\/[^\/]+\/)([^\/]+)/. This will catch anything after search and the next slash (e.g. `/search/abc/Query Here/` or `/search/hi-there-cute-bunny/Query Here/` or things like that). Updated jsFiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/zSBkL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Regexp seems unnecessary here.

If I understand correctly, and assuming you don't care about the sequence number, then you should be able to use the far more economical `indexOf()`.

javascript:

```
if (window.location.hash.replace('#','').indexOf('/search/option') == 1 ) {
    ...
}
```

`replace('#','')` is necessary as some browsers include '#' in `location.hash` and some don't. By eliminating '#' if present, you can test `indexOf(...) == 1`, which is more specific than `indexOf(...) > -1 )`.